# Отключение функций кнопки/ссылки и вывод сообщения

Tags: javascript, jquery, инспекция-кода

Доброго врмени суток!
Требуется реализовать блокировку функций кнопки и оповестить об этом пользователя. 
С начала хотел сделать простым способом:

```
$('#btn').prop('disabled', 'true');
```

Но потом решил, что будет не информативно и решил добавить оповещение при нажатии:

```
    var areaType = $("#types").val();
    // При определенном условии кнпоки должны блокироваться/отображаться
    (areaType != "uslov") ? hideBtn() : showBtn();

    function hideBtn() {
        $("[type = 'submit']").attr('onclick', 'return false');
        $("[type = 'submit']").click(function () {
            alert("Error!");
        });

        $("[role='group']").children().attr("onclick", 'return false');
        $("[role='group']").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("Error!");
        });
    }

    function showBtn() {
        $("[type = 'submit']").prop("disabled", false);
        $("[role='group']").children().prop("disabled", false);
    }
```

Понимаю, что код не идеальный, поэтому хотелось бы узнать, как можно реализовать данный функционал по другому?

Comment: в чем смысл использовать выражение там, где не используется его значение? `(areaType != "uslov") ? hideBtn() : showBtn();`? просто ради того, чтобы в одну строку записать?

Comment: а этот код работает вообще?

Comment: Да, работает. Вы правы, можно сделать с помощью 'if'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо за ответы и замечания. Решил сделать, следующим образом:

```
    var areaType = $("#types").val();  

    if (areaType != "uslov") hideBtn();

    function hideBtn() {
        $("[type = 'submit'],[type = 'button']").attr('onclick', 'return false');
        $("[type = 'submit'],[type = 'button'],a:contains('Link')").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("Error!");
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Скопировал ваш функционал. Форму по-прежнему можно отправить через Enter + в "заблокированные" инпуты можно вводить текст.
UPD: Добавил снятие фокуса при клике на "заблокированном" поле, что усложняет отправку "заблокированной" формы.

```js
// "блокируем"/"разблокируем" форму
function toggleForm(state) {
  $("[type = 'submit']").toggleClass('disabled', state);
  $("[role='group']").children().toggleClass('disabled', state);
}

// Проверка введенного пароля
function checkPassword() {
  var areaType = $("#types").val();
  toggleForm(areaType != "uslov");
}

// Реакция для "заблокированной" формы
$('body').on('click', '.disabled', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).blur();
  alert("Error!");
});

// Проверяем пароль по мере ввода
$('body').on('change input blur', '#types', checkPassword);

checkPassword();
```

```css
.disabled {
  background: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  Types: <input id="types" />
  <div role="group">
    <input id="i1" /><br />
    <input id="i2" />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам, но есть одно условие, "#types" скрытый инпут, которые получает значение с сервера. И дочерние элементы "[role='group'] имеют тип "submit". Проще говоря 3 кнопки и одна ссылка(ещё должна быть), если значение с сервера равно "uslov", то кнопки не доступны и при нажатии должна всплывать подсказка, почему кнопки не доступны

Comment: Если бы задаете значение `#types` на сервер-сайде и пользователь не может его поменять, то зачем тогда делать проверку на фронте?  Вы можете в случае `#types != 'uslov'` сразу навешивать всем, кому нужно, класс `disabled`. И если вы добавите ваш html-код, то будет намного проще.

Comment: Я так и сделал, но решил не выключать кнопки, но убрать их функционал, что бы при нажатии на них выходило сообщение. Поэтому я и хотел узнать, как будет правильнее реализовать данный функционал. Также хотел узнать, как можно более лаконично реализовать все это дело.